# How toI convert a Data gridview column to a list of strings?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to convert the first column from a *Data Grid View* to a *list of string*, then search through the list and highlight the corresponding row in red.

This is what I currently have

```
 Dim search As String = txtsearch.Text
 Dim lsttitlesort As New List(Of String)()

        For i = 0 To dgvbooks.Rows.Count - 1
            lsttitlesort.Add(dgvbooks(0, i).Value)
        Next
        For i As Integer = 1 To lsttitle.Count - 1
            If lsttitlesort(i).ToLower.Contains(search.ToLower) Then
                dgvbooks.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
            End If
        Next
```

The problem is that when I try to run it, it crashes and displays an error message saying

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I'm new to *Data Grid Views*: can you explain me how to fix it?

Comment: Your error consist in “lsttitle.Count – 1”.  You are iterating a list and inside you are getting element from another. Are you sure those lists ( “lsttitlesort” and  “lsttitle”) have the same content length also those indexes are in relation with dgvbooks row indexes?
Also be sure "lsttitlesort(i)" is not Nothing before calling “.ToLower” property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search directly on the `DataGridView` without using a list:

```vb
Dim search As String = txtsearch.Text

'iterate through all rows of the DataGridView to search the value.
For Each dgrBook As DataGridViewRow In dgvbooks.Rows

    'you can skip the new row at the end (if available).
    If dgrBook.IsNewRow Then
        Continue For
    End If

    'check if first column contains the search value.
    'if search value found on first column set the background color to red, 
    'otherwise reset the background to white.
    If CStr(dgrBook.Cells(0).Value & "").ToLower.Contains(search.ToLower) Then
        dgrBook.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
    Else
        dgrBook.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
    End If 
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it and it underlines dgrbook.cells(0) in red and a message that reads "Datagridviewcell can't be convert to 'String'"

Comment: @DMFisher - I forget the `.Value`. fixed.

Comment: The "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" error appears on the line "If CStr(dgrBook.Cells(0).Value).ToLower.Contains(search.ToLower) Then".

Comment: Ay That did it. Thank you so much.